# Import csv file in postgresql using scala

Tags: postgresql, scala

i am new to scala and need to write a code which can import csv file into postgresql table using scala.Can anyone help regarding this ?

Comment: abssab, what have you already done/tried? Where specifically do you have issues? StackOverflow is not "coding for free" site but we (the SO community) are typically willing to help our colleagues who shown some actual effort

Comment: Really sorry.But do not know,where I need to start.Just got a task around a day ago and confused from where i need to pick this .That's why asking help to start

Comment: absaab, do you know how to open and read a CSV file? do you know how to open a connection to PorstgreSQL and execute insert query?

Comment: Use this https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv library to convert csv into list of data. Now, you can store these data to whatever database you need.

Comment: @SergGr:No ,i am not at that stage ,reading the scala tutorials to proceed.If you've something then please guide me as it will be great help .

Comment: @RaKa:Many thanks for the information ,however i'm confused on that part and not able to proceed further.COuld you please guide me about sample code.